# Using abstract entity

Tags: entity-framework, abstract

I'd like to use generalization in my EF model (.edmx) using an abstract base entity.

So I made the following

[image: abstract entity]

I set the abstraction flag on the base entity

[image: abstract setting]

The expected output would something like the following

[image: desired result]

However when I look at the generated SQL I notice that it's creating my abstract base table which I do not want.
The problem is that the Id in either ConcreteEntity_A or ConcreteEntity_B can be the same so if it's also being added to the base entity I have a problem.

```
-- Creating table 'AbstractBaseSet'
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[AbstractBaseSet] (
    [Id] int NOT NULL
);
GO

-- Creating table 'AbstractBaseSet_ConcreteEntity_A'
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[AbstractBaseSet_ConcreteEntity_A] (
    [Id] int  NOT NULL
);
GO

-- Creating table 'AbstractBaseSet_ConcreteEntity_B'
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[AbstractBaseSet_ConcreteEntity_B] (
    [Id] int  NOT NULL
);
GO
```

Have I misunderstood the use of abstract entities?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No you didn't but it is simply the way how EF works if you use relation with the base entity - entity must have a table (even if it is abstract) to be able to create relation. If you want the expected model you must move the relation to derived tables.

Comment: The base table still gets created when I move the relations to the derived tables

Comment: Are you using model first (generating database from model)? Model first uses TPT inheritance where base class has its own table.

Comment: Yes, I'm using model first and it's to late to change it. So I guess I can't use generalization here :(

Comment: It is in theory possible to change generation process - check database generation power pack. There should be also option to use TPH inheritance. You will have to check how the power pack creates mapping and SQL and create a new one for TPC inheritance.

Comment: Turning off the default code generation have caused me all kinds of headaches in the past, so I'm reluctant to do it. However I didn't know about this power pack. I'll have to play around with that when I get some play time :)